# Conditional in Django Tables

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-tables2

I am trying to include a conditional in my Django table, but I am having some issues finding the correct syntax to do so.

I have a boolean field in one of my models, and based on that value - I would like to render a different `label_link` and callback url for that specific db record.

Here is the code I am using:

```
class Feature(BaseTable):
    orderable = False
    title_english = tables.Column()
    featured_item = tables.Column()
    if (featured_item == False):
        actions = tables.TemplateColumn("""
        {% url 'add_feature' pk=record.pk as url_ %}
        {% label_link url_ 'Add to Features' %}
        """, attrs=dict(cell={'class': 'span1'}))
    else:
        actions = tables.TemplateColumn("""
        {% url 'remove_feature' pk=record.pk as url_ %}
        {% label_link url_ 'Remove From Features' %}
        """, attrs=dict(cell={'class': 'span1'}))
```

Now I am aware currently that this is just checking to see if the value exists - therefore always rendering the code under the `else` statement.

I have been unable to find any documentation that covers this particular nuance of Django tables.

Note: I'm using Django 1.5 and Python 2.7

Comment: What is the actual issue you are having? Also, `if not featured_item:` will work too, and looks nicer ;)

Comment: If the item is a `featured` item, then I want the label_link to read "Remove From Features" with the callback URL of `remove_feature`. And vice-versa if the item is not a `featured` item

Comment: I have not used this kind of table before, but this sounds like the kind of thing you want to do in your template rather than the table object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put the if statement in the `Feature` class - it is processed when the class is loaded, so you don't have access to the table data yet.

Inside the `TemplateColumn`, you can access the current row of the table with `record`, so you could move the logic there.

```
class Feature(BaseTable):
    ...
    actions = tables.TemplateColumn("""
    {% if not record.featured_item %}
    {% url 'add_feature' pk=record.pk as url_ %}
    {% label_link url_ 'Add to Features' %}
    {% else %}
    {% url 'remove_feature' pk=record.pk as url_ %}
    {% label_link url_ 'Remove From Features' %}
    {% endif %}
    """, attrs=dict(cell={'class': 'span1'}))
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. This worked like a charm.